# Python regular expressions - how to capture the rest of text which is uncaptured

Tags: python, regex, text

Dear Community members!

I am struggling to figure out regex problem.
Objective is to **split the text in separate parts with keyword (consectetur|tempor incididunt|proident|consequat) as a separator and add keyword to the text part captured. Start capturing new group again until another keyword is spotted.** Unfortunatly, I am stuck to find a solution for capturing the last bit of text, which has no keywords and has to be added to the end of last capture group or new group. Is that even possible to solve using regex?

**Please, pay attention to links at the bottom**

**Regular expression:** (.*?)(consectetur|tempor incididunt|proident|consequat)

**Text:** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

**Desired outcome:**

Match 1

1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
2. consectetur

Match 2

1. adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
2. tempor incididunt

Match 3

1. ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
2. consequat

Match 4

1. . Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
2. proident
3. sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

**Below, I have attached supporting information with what I have so far:**

- [Screenshot of above-mentioned problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTbJl.jpg)
- [Link to regex tester with all the fields filled](https://pythex.org/?regex=(.*%3F)(consectetur%7Ctempor%20incididunt%7Cproident%7Cconsequat)&test_string=Lorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet%2C%20consectetur%20adipiscing%20elit%2C%20sed%20do%20eiusmod%20tempor%20incididunt%20ut%20labore%20et%20dolore%20magna%20aliqua.%20Ut%20enim%20ad%20minim%20veniam%2C%20quis%20nostrud%20exercitation%20ullamco%20laboris%20nisi%20ut%20aliquip%20ex%20ea%20commodo%20consequat.%20Duis%20aute%20irure%20dolor%20in%20reprehenderit%20in%20voluptate%20velit%20esse%20cillum%20dolore%20eu%20fugiat%20nulla%20pariatur.%20Excepteur%20sint%20occaecat%20cupidatat%20non%20proident%2C%20sunt%20in%20culpa%20qui%20officia%20deserunt%20mollit%20anim%20id%20est%20laborum.&ignorecase=1&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: I think you want `(?s).*?(?:consectetur|tempor incididunt|proident|consequat|\Z)`

Comment: Please add your regular expression and a **minimal** example of input and desired output (also as text) to your question!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you very much for your answer! I have put "\Z" as one of the keywords and it helped.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you for the suggestion! Corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
(.*?)(consectetur|tempor incididunt|proident|consequat|\Z)
```

The `\Z` matches the very end of text in Python. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5zxiWR/1).

So, the pattern now matches:

- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first occurrence of
- `(consectetur|tempor incididunt|proident|consequat|\Z)` - any of the alternatives: `consectetur`, `tempor`, `incididunt`, `proident`, `consequat` or end of string.

If the string can have line breaks, use the `re.DOTALL` flag when you compile the regex:

```
rx = re.compile(r'(.*?)(consectetur|tempor incididunt|proident|consequat|\Z)', re.DOTALL)
```